# Struct Not Completing Sort

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, struct

Basicly Here is my assignment **I'M NOT ASKING YOU TO COMPLETE THIS ASSIGNMENT, JUST ASSIST ME.**

Sort an Array of Structs

In this assignment, you are to create an array of structs and sort
the array.

1. create a struct with (at least) 3 fields
2. create an array of structs
3. read data into the array of structs (10 to 15 records)
4. print the array
5. sort the array (in ascending order) on 1 field of the struct
6. print the array
7. sort the array (in descending order) on another field of the struct
8. print the array

I am currently stuck on step 5.

this is my program as of now.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

struct data {
  int a,b,c;
} number [10];

int main(){
 int enterData;
 int *temp = new int[3];

 for (int i = 0; i<10; i++){
  //for (int n = 0; n<=3; n++){
   cin>> number[i].a;
   cin>> number[i].b;
   cin>> number[i].c;
  if(i >= 10) break;
  //}
 }

 for (int i = 0; i<10; i++){
 // for (int n = 0; n<=3; n++){
   cout << number[i].a << " ";
   cout << number[i].b << " ";
   cout << number[i].c << " ";
   cout << "\n";
   if(i >= 10) break;
 // }
 }

 cout <<"\n\n\n";

 for (int i = 0; i<9; i++){
  if (number[i].a > number[i+1].a){
   temp[0] = number[i].a;
   temp[1] = number[i].b;
   temp[2] = number[i].c;
   number[i].a = number[i+1].a;
   number[i].b = number[i+1].b;
   number[i].c = number[i+1].c;
   number[i+1].a = temp[0];
   number[i+1].b = temp[1];
   number[i+1].c = temp[2];
  }
 }
 for (int i = 0; i<10; i++){
 // for (int n = 0; n<=3; n++){
   cout << number[i].a << " ";
   cout << number[i].b << " ";
   cout << number[i].c << " ";
   cout << "\n";
   if(i >= 10) break;
 // }
 }
}
```

And this is my current output.

Numbers Entered in to the Program
3 4 8
7 6 4
2 9 0
1 4 2
5 3 6
7 3 2
3 4 5
6 7 8
9 5 4
7 5 1

First "Sort"
3 4 8
2 9 0
1 4 2
5 3 6
7 6 4
3 4 5
6 7 8
7 3 2
7 5 1
9 5 4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this code

```
 for (int i = 0; i<10; i++){
  //for (int n = 0; n<=3; n++){
   cin>> number[i].a;
   cin>> number[i].b;
   cin>> number[i].c;
  if(i >= 10) break;
  //}
 }
```

There is no point in having this statement `if(i >= 10) break`, because the look exists when the exit criteria is met, i.e. `i<10`.

The problem is here:

```
 for (int i = 0; i<9; i++){
  if (number[i].a > number[i+1].a){
   temp[0] = number[i].a;
   temp[1] = number[i].b;
   temp[2] = number[i].c;
   number[i].a = number[i+1].a;
   number[i].b = number[i+1].b;
   number[i].c = number[i+1].c;
   number[i+1].a = temp[0];
   number[i+1].b = temp[1];
   number[i+1].c = temp[2];
  }
 }
```

You only loop once through the array. The simplest sorting algorithm, bubble sort, requires a double loop:

```
 for (int i = 0; i<10; i++){
 for (int j = 0; j<9; j++){
  if (number[j].a > number[j+1].a){
   temp[0] = number[j].a;
   temp[1] = number[j].b;
   temp[2] = number[j].c;
   number[j].a = number[j+1].a;
   number[j].b = number[j+1].b;
   number[j].c = number[j+1].c;
   number[j+1].a = temp[0];
   number[j+1].b = temp[1];
   number[j+1].c = temp[2];
  }
 }
```

Notice that this is not necessary:

```
int *temp = new int[3];
```

You could use your `data` struct.

```
 data temp;

 for (int i = 0; i<10; i++){
 for (int j = 0; j<9; j++){
  if (number[j].a > number[j+1].a){
   temp.a = number[j].a;
   temp.b = number[j].b;
   temp.c = number[j].c;
   number[j].a = number[j+1].a;
   number[j].b = number[j+1].b;
   number[j].c = number[j+1].c;
   number[j+1].a = temp.a;
   number[j+1].b = temp.b;
   number[j+1].c = temp.c;
  }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I been up too late I believe. But once again thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way to force it work - to add `for(int j=0; j<10; j++)` just above sort `for`.

Answer (score -1):

You can using qsort http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/qsort/ for sorting array of structures, and when you not need writing your own sorting code.

Comment: In C++ there is no reason at all to use `qsort` over `std::sort` .